# Is my new gTLD causing it to get filtered as spam?

Tags: email, spam, ironport

I have a domain called "*******.international". I decided to go with the new gTLD because it fits the name of the company pretty well.

I have an automated emailer setup to send emails to our clients' emails and I've noticed that a few companies are actively rejecting the emails. When I look at the log, I read this:

```
Remote Server returned '<[*.*.*.*] #5.0.0 smtp; 5.1.0 - Unknown address error 554-'mailfrom without country or top level domain is administratively denied' (delivery attempts: 0)>'
X-IronPort-Anti-Spam-Filtered: true
```

Is this caused by using a gTLD? Is there anything I could do to allow these emails to go through?

Comment: https://twitter.com/jamesthomson/status/454332436214972416

Comment: And, are you absolutely 100% _certain_ that your mailer is using the correct envelope sender? Your question does not indicate that you even checked.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The answer is yes, you're being blocked because of your gTLD.

I sincerely doubt you'll ever escape the pain of getting your emails rejected from a gTLD of ".international". Playing a game of whack-a-mole with colleagues, clients, suppliers, and partners will get old very quickly. Until absolutely every spam filter is corrected by the developer to include .international as a valid .gTLD (and decides to trust it... see .biz), then you'll have rejections.

I would highly recommend that you switch your mailing domain to a .com, .net, or something similar. Feel free to accept email on .international, but sending anything either from that server (mail.company.international) or from an address (joe@company.international) will just give you headaches for years.

Comment: And that's what I am telling everyone asking me if they need such a shiny new gTLD domain. Essentially, they are useless - but since there is *still* so much money in the domain market ...

Comment: I'd say they're useful for cute websites, url shorteners, or other such stuff.  Definitely not email, though.

Comment: @Hyppy url shorteners? `.international` by itself is longer than some complete host names of other domains.

Comment: Not only that: you'll also have fun registering accounts on many websites with a long TLD since so many apps get e-mail validation wrong.

Comment: Aye, but <customtext>.go.international is a lot easier to remember than https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QP0VL1fnOeRlIsN70UT-kWwYVomyMR3LA2tQLzC3ByE/edit?authkey=CJvO1eEJ&hl=en#

Comment: Given that .anything domains have been unleashed and rapidly being taken up by large established brands, this heavyweight backing is going to encourage mail server software/service providers/validators to get their houses in order quite quickly.

Comment: @JamesRyan, that hasn't been the case for many, *many* other things (EDNS0, ICMP, IPv6, DNSSEC, ...); my prediction for what will happen here is that the "large established brands" are quickly going to realise what an absolute clusterfudge this is all going to be, and they'll go back to using their `.com`.  Not that ICANN will mind, they've got the cash already.

Comment: @womble none of those are directly used for advertising. All non tech people will understand is that email doesn't work for those domains.

Comment: And the tech people will say "we can't fix it", repeatedly, until the non-tech people give up and go back to their `.com`.

Answer (score 13):

Yep. Congratulations, you are the first victim I learned about.

You can try to contact the host in question and inform them the world has changed, and new TLDs exist.

Comment: Yes! Send them an email... Oh wait... :)

Comment: @billpg: I left this as an excercise to the student. You passed :) Fun aside, I doubt that you can even order one of those shiny new domains without having a working e-mail address (likely in a classic gTLD).

Answer (score 8):

Yes they are blocking it because of the gtld.

You can email them (from a .com email address) and ask them nicely to fix their spam filter...assuming they want your emails.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that indeed would be the case. There is little awareness present in the developer community about the plurality of new TLD extensions that have become available in recent years. Also, since most of the developers are not aware of their presence, the large-scale adoption of these new TLD extensions is getting hindered and that has turned into a chicken and egg problem.

However, there is a systematic effort underway to tackle this vicious cycle. The ["Universal Acceptance Steering Group"](http://uasg.tech) is working extensively on raising overall awareness about Internationalized Domain Names and E-mail Address Internationalization, among end-users, software developers, policy makers and thought leaders. If you find it interesting, you can join it and make a difference.